# JAVA : how to repeat string in multiple lines

Tags: java, string

I'm looking for a simple way to repeat a same string in multiple lines.
eg. String str = "ABC";

How to make the output looks like this by using For loop:

ABCABCABC

ABCABCABC

ABCABCABC

Comment: Two loops (well, technically don't even need loops..). Can be nested or not. What has, uhh .. been tried? And what problem is there with it?

Answer (score 0):

Any baic for loop inside a loop example would have given you example. This can't be done with a single loop.

```
String str = "ABC";

for(int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
{
  for(int j=0; i <=3; j++)
    System.out.print(str);
  System.out.println("");
}
```

If you don't want to write loop inside another loop, you can use one loop first to build one  single line. And use another loop outside of first one to print this line repeatedly.

```
String line = "";
for(int i=0; i <=3; i++)
        line += str;

for(int i = 0; i <=3; i++)
   System.out.prinln(line);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is use a nested for loop (i.e. a loop inside a loop).
The outer loop will print line by line by first printing the string, then starting new line. A new line is added by `System.out.println();`, while the string itself is generated by another (inner) loop. The inner loop would repeat the String 3 times in a row.

Note that you should use `print` instead of `println` in order to print sentences next to each other.

The final code looks like this.

```
String str = "ABC";
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        System.out.print(str);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"No loops necessary" (aka the operations that happen for a fixed `m` and `n`):

```
String str = "ABC";
String line = str + str + str;
System.out.println(line);
System.out.println(line);
System.out.println(line);
```

Or (note the change in the loop position):

```
String str = "ABC";
System.out.println(str + str + str);
System.out.println(str + str + str);
System.out.println(str + str + str);
```

Or even (more explicit of change in loop position):

```
String str = "ABC";
PrintStream out = System.out;
out.print(str); out.print(str); out.print(str); out.println("");
out.print(str); out.print(str); out.print(str); out.println("");
out.print(str); out.print(str); out.print(str); out.println("");
```

Now, how can this be converted into loops? That is, *which part(s)* - or operations - are repeated? How/why?

As shown, there are ultimately two loops for printing out `str` in an arbitrary `m` x `n` manner; they can be nested or not nested. Take the above fixed example and simply change the static copy'n'paste "loops" into a `for (int m = 0; m < countM; m++)` syntax; what does this result in?